# Foreach Inside foreach Add Values to Array

Tags: php

In my project, I'm trying to disable booked days in datepicker.
I have reservations table all recorded reservations are stored in here. And before the estate detail page, I'm checking the available days from the reservation table.

Before checking I calculate the between dates of reservation.

Problem is, there can be many reservations on the same estate but when I query I only takes the first record of the reservation so other days showing available. Like below it only takes reservation 1 dates

**Example**

```
Rezervation 1 Dates : 05.05.2019  - 10.05.2019
Rezervation 2 Dates : 05.05.2019  - 10.05.2019
```

Reservations are coming as an array i tried to make foreach inside foreach and tried to add data to variable but cant success.

My codes are like below;

```
function datebeetween($reservations){

    $data = [];

    if(!empty($reservations)) {

        foreach($reservationsas $rezer){

        $days = array();
        $start = Carbon\Carbon::parse($rezer['entry_date']);
        $end = Carbon\Carbon::parse($rezer['out_date']);
        $dateRange = Carbon\CarbonPeriod::create($start, $end);

            foreach ($dateRange as $date) {

            $days[] = $date->format('d-m-Y');

            }
            $data[] = $days;
        return $data;

        }
        }else{

    return $data;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you indented the code correctly...

```
    foreach($reservations as $rezer){
        $days = array();
        $start = Carbon\Carbon::parse($rezer['entry_date']);
        $end = Carbon\Carbon::parse($rezer['out_date']);
        $dateRange = Carbon\CarbonPeriod::create($start, $end);

        foreach ($dateRange as $date) {
            $days[] = $date->format('d-m-Y');
        }
        $data[] = $days;
        return $data;
    }
```

you would see that the `return` is inside the outer `foreach()`, so move this outside one level and it should return all of the data.

```
        $data = array_unique(array_merge($data,$days));
    }
    return $data;
```

Comment: yeah my bad. I moved outside the loop but this time its showing array inxside array like below;
[["08-05-2019","09-05-2019","10-05-2019","11-05-2019"],["15-05-2019","16-05-2019","17-05-2019","18-05-2019"]]

Comment: So do you need to build the `$days` array, so just add each item into `$data`, or do you want to merge the two arrays so you only have unique dates?

Comment: yes bro exactly i want to merge two arrays as unique days

Comment: I've done a simple fix - in the last code example I've changed the line to `$data = array_unique(array_merge($data,$days));`

Comment: thank you very much bro. Now its working as expected:)